# How to group by on first table row many to many relation with left join in LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, group-by, many-to-many

How can I group by complaint in this scenario?

I get all Data with left join with bellow query
now I want all the application users grouped for every related complaint row
my mean one complaint should have many users that is assigned to how should I group users by
complaint and how to loop through it in order to assign the grouped users to any ViewModel
property

```cs
public class Complaint
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Complaint{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<AsignComplaintToUsers> asignComplaintToUsers { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AsignComplaintToUsers> asignComplaintToUsers { get; set; }
}

public class AsignComplaintToUsers
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ComplaintId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ComplaintId")]
    public Complaint complaint { get; set; }


    public string? AsignToId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AsignTo")]
    public ApplicationUser applicationUser { get; set; }

    public string? AsignById { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var xyz = 
    (from c in _context.complaints
    join AC in _context.asignComplaintToUsers
        on c.Id equals AC.ComplaintId into temp
    from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

    join AppUser in _context.applicationUsers
        on t.AsignTo equals AppUser.Id into temp2
    from t2 in temp2.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new
    {
        complaint = c,
        asugnSugessionTousers = t,
        usersWhoAsignedComplaints = t2

    })
    .ToList();
```

Now I want to have list of all user assigned to each complaint, so how can I do that please?

Comment: Can you  show expected result class?

Comment: I need a list witch contains all complaints with sub list of users witch related to each complaint

Comment: I do not need words, show result class. Or you do final query into anonymous classes?

Comment: Yes I want to put query result in anonymous class